# Help with $\int_{0}^{\pi /2}\arccos\frac{\cos(x)}{1+2\cos(x)}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

I've been struggling with this integral for a few days.

$$\int_{0}^{\pi /2}\!\arccos\left(\frac{\cos(x)}{1+2\cos(x)}\right)dx$$

Any help would be appreciated. Cheers.

Comment: This video might help https://youtu.be/1FixkRTDem0

Comment: You may post some of your work related to the struggle. That helps people here to help you in much better way. Just posting a tough question without any context is not encouraged and usually such questions get closed soon.

Comment: See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4037652/solve-int-0-pi-2-arccos-left-dfrac-cosx12-cosx-right-dx) also.

Answer (score 4):

This is the so-called **Coxeter integral**. It is related to *Ahmed integrals*. You can refer to [this](https://t1.daumcdn.net/cfile/tistory/1176F84E4F31112B11?download) and [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1FixkRTDem0) for calculating it. The result is
$$
\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\arccos \left (\frac{ \cos(x)}{1+2 \cos(x)}\right )dx=\frac{5\pi^2}{24}
$$

Also you can find more on [this page](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h1674162p10667425).

Comment: I saw solution of the integral. The first step is to simplify the integrand and then maybe integration by parts — but Feynman algorithm shall definitely be used in order to compute integral. I found the document wherein I discerned solution but can't attach so you would see it. Integral is rather simple but from the point of technical view :)

Comment: Search in Google: Two very challenging calculus problems. You will, should you have not yet, understand about what I am speaking of.

Comment: Could you please put a link here? I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: https://www.math.ucla.edu/~josephbreen/Some_Very_Challenging_Calculus_Problems-2.pdf

Comment: @Lmnop OK, but the series was solved by *Mathematica* in $0.0003$ sec, while the integral... no way!