# Solve $\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \arccos\left( \frac{\cos(x)}{1+2\cos(x)} \right) \mathrm dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

> $$\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \cos^{-1}\left( \dfrac{\cos(x)}{1+2\cos(x)} \right) \,dx$$

The final answer is: $\dfrac{5\pi^2}{24}$

Comment: What have you tried? What is the context for your problem?

Comment: tried substituition first... there is no scope for that as far as i know... tried by parts... and it just got complicated...

Comment: What about your context? Why are you doing this problem? Edit all your attempts and explanations into your post, don't respond to me as a comment.

Comment: Look up for Coxeter’s Integrals, e.g. http://cfile22.uf.tistory.com/attach/1176F84E4F31112B111C67

Comment: this is a *hard* integral. Any answer using high-school level techniques would be very long and potentially hard to follow

Comment: Why is this given a precalculus tag? This is like a calc. 10 integral.

Comment: @BobaFret It was my mistake, I didn't know that it was a tough integral, I have edited the tag.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is the method to evaluate this integral.
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Source:-**  Some very challenging calculus problems by Joseph Breen

Comment: is there a simpler way? shorter?

Comment: I don't think that there is some shorter method. This seems long if you don't know ahmed integral.$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\tan^{-1}\sqrt{x^{2}+2}}{(x^{2}+1)\sqrt{x^{2}+2}}\mathop{\mathrm{d}x}=\frac{5\pi ^{2}}{96}$