# Calculate $\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\arccos\frac{\cos x}{1+2\cos x}\,\mathrm dx.$

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometric-integrals

I've stumbled across this definite integral and was unable to find a closed form, can anyone help me out?

This integral $I$ is defined as follows:
$$
I \equiv \int_{0}^{\pi/2}\arccos\left(\frac{\cos(x)}{1+2\cos(x)}\right)dx
$$

To solve this problem, I've tried to incorporate the double angle identity $\cos(2\theta) = 2\cos^2(\theta)-1$ as follows:

Isolate $\theta$
$$
2\theta = \arccos(2\cos^2(\theta)-1)
$$
Let $$\alpha = 2\cos^2(\theta)-1$$
After substituting and some manipulation
$$
\theta = \arccos\left(\sqrt{\frac{1+\alpha}{2}}\right)
$$
Hence
$$
\arccos(\alpha) = 2\arccos\left(\sqrt{\frac{1+\alpha}{2}}\right)
$$
This finding enables us to rewrite $I$ as the following
$$
I = \int_{0}^{\pi/2}2\arccos\left(\sqrt{\frac{1+3\cos(x)}{2+4\cos(x)}}\right)dx
$$
However, I am not sure how to continue from here, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: To get rid of the $\arccos$ we could integrate by parts with $dv=dx$.

Comment: FWIW, an approximate numerical answer is 2.05617.

Comment: @aschepler I'll try that, thanks.

Comment: @Dan the given solution is $\frac{5\pi^2}{24}$, I'm just not sure how to find it.

Comment: A solution can be found [here](https://www.math.ucla.edu/~josephbreen/Some_Very_Challenging_Calculus_Problems-2.pdf).

Comment: Okay, thank you!

Comment: For a (hopefully) simpler solution, your integral can be rewritten as $$I_1=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sec^{-1}(\sec x + 2)dx$$ with inverse $$I_2=\int_{\sec^{-1}(3)}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sec^{-1}(\sec y - 2)dy$$ Pictorally, the two integrals add up to the area of the square $$I_1+I_2 = \frac{\pi^2}{4}$$ If you can prove that $I_1 = 5 I_2$, the proof is complete.

Comment: That is a creative method, I will definitely try to prove that. Thanks!

Comment: see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4037652/solve-int-0-pi-2-arccos-left-frac-cosx12-cosx-right-mathrm